# Is it good idea to store python package eggs in artifactory?

Tags: python, artifactory

Currently I am developing automated test framework.  This test-framework has different packages.  These packages will be refer in different project and these may be  modified locally by the developer. I want to manage the python package eggs. I am thinking of using Artifactory. I tried to look for Artifactory help for Python,But I couldn't get anything useful.
should I use Artifactory or PIP ?

**Edit:**
Is there any way or command in python which can help me to put the eggs in artifactory?

Comment: Sorry, completely offtopic but: I am the only one who saw the headline and thought of "snake omelette"?

Comment: @SJuan76 hmm... :-).. well python packages can be provided as eggs(I don't know why they keep this name) same way as we provide jar file for java packages.

Comment: Is this connected to your other post "How to put any file in artifactory using Python": http://stackoverflow.com/q/11514693/1395668?

Comment: @Rakesh I presume it's related to the idea of snakes laying eggs, but I guess there could by a skit I don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are numerous reasons to prefer a binary repository manager over a simple shared directory/SCM binary storage:

1. Fine grained security.
2. Ability to proxy and cache remote repositories.
3. More efficient handling of binaries (because it's a tool that's tailored to do so).
4. Sharing the binaries with other teams and the world is a lot safer and easier.
5. Integration with many tools in the ecosystem.
6. Search and manipulation facilities.
7. Administration tools.

Artifactory exposes a very rich [REST API](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API) and the deployment of any artifact can be achieved by a simple HTTP PUT request.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the Defend Against Fruit project. It provides the previously missing glue between Python and Artifactory.
http://teamfruit.github.io/defend_against_fruit/

Answer (score 2):

You can use "in house" PyPi (either with `easy_install -f ...` or `pip -f ...`).

For a server you can have just Apache serving a directory with all the eggs or something like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver