# How to put any file in artifactory using python?

Tags: python, artifactory, artifact

I have a requirement where any file should be put in the artifact using python language. I tried to search all over internet but I couldn't find any help.

Please share code snippet or something which can help me to achieve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated here.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to upload artifacts into Artifactory using a Python client?

Comment: Translate this to python: curl -X PUT --data-binary @absolute_path/ivy.xml -u deployer:password -i http://your_host/artifactory/ext-releases-local2/org/apache/ant/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ivy.xml

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. what was your solution?

Answer (score 8):

Artifactory python module can be used to upload artifacts into artifactory.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/artifactory/0.1.17

Here is an example from the website used to upload a file into artifactory:

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
path = ArtifactoryPath("http://my-artifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshotlocal/myapp/1.0")
path.mkdir()

path.deploy_file('./myapp-1.0.tar.gz')
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14024943)

Comment: @JamesK added an example, incase the link becomes invalid

Answer (score 4):

Artifactory exposes a REST API. Here's a link to the [documentation](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#ArtifactorysRESTAPI-DeployArtifact). See the section on "Deploy Artifact".

Basically you will need to build a REST client. There might already exist one for Artifactory? If you need to write it yourself there is a WADL file that might make things easier (see also [wadllib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wadllib/1.1.4)).

Answer (score 4):

The defend against fruit project provides the integration with Artifactory and Python you are looking for.
http://teamfruit.github.io/defend_against_fruit/

Comment: While I do really like the approach taken by DefendAgainstFruit, it seems that is has two big problems: seems to be able to deploy only python modules. Second issue is not related to the question: is that it does supports only Artifactory on the output side, as it would be nice it would be able to deploy to other similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

"pyartifactory" provides the REST API functionality you are looking for.

"pyartifactory" is an alternative to "artifactory". It differs by providing more concise methods.

pyartifactory: https://pypi.org/project/pyartifactory/

Their provided "Download an artifact" example:

```
artifact = art.artifacts.download("<ARTIFACT_PATH_IN_ARTIFACTORY>", "<LOCAL_DIRECTORY_PATH>")
# artifact = art.artifacts.download("my-artifactory-repository/my/new/artifact/file.txt", "Desktop/my/local/directory")
# The artifact location is returned by the download method
# If you have not set a <LOCAL_DIRECTORY_PATH>, the artifact will be downloaded in the current directory
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).