# Using Jenkins to publish tar.gz to Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

This is problem I am trying to solve:

1. checkout code from Github to a local directory D
2. run configure command inside directory D
3. create a tar.gz for directory
4. upload taz.gz file to Nexus

I am stuck at step 3:
- I can specify the version in Maven pom.xml file, but is there a way to automatically create a build version every time Jenkins is run?
- If I specify tar.gz in pom.xml file, I would get: Unknown packaging: gz @ line 6, column 13

If I specify jar inside packaging, there is no error, and files are upload to Nexus successfully.

Any advice would help, thanks!

==

follow suggestion, I am using Assembly Plugin, but still having trouble create tar.gz for Directory RE

**Here is my pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.o$
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Auc</groupId>
<artifactId>RE</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.112</version>
<!-- <packaging>tgz</packaging> -->
<name>RE Repository</name>
<url>http://nexus1.ccorp.com/nexus</url>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.6</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <configuration>
           <descriptors>
             <descriptor>format.xml</descriptor>
           </descriptors>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Here is my format.xml file**, RE directory is where I checked out the code and want to create tar.gz for it

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
       <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <moduleSets>
            <moduleSet>
                    <sources>
                            <fileSets>
                                    <fileSet>
                                            <directory>/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/nightly_build/workspace/RE</directory>
                                    </fileSet>
                            </fileSets>
                    </sources>
            </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Nexus or Artifactory store simple tar.gz artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054950/can-nexus-or-artifactory-store-simple-tar-gz-artifacts)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what we end up with:

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=Home -DartifactId=RE -Dversion=0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=tar.gz -DrepositoryId=Auc -Durl=http://nexus1.ccorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots -Dfile=RE-0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
```

Make sure -DrepositoryId=Auc, Auc is the deployment id you set in your setting.xml

```
<server>
  <id>Auc</id>
  <username>deployment</username>
  <password>deployment123</password>
</server>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create the tar.gz and then you can deploy it as usual with

```
mvn clean deploy
```

and the right settings.xml available on Jenkins with credentails as needed for the deployment.